# Question about filtering using mongoose or just JS filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, filter

I am using express + mongoose, and sometimes I find that to do some queries is so complicated, so what I am doing is getting the object by id. Eg:

```
const ticketObj = await Ticket.findById(ticketId);
```

and then I filter using JS filter

```
ticketObj.comments = ticketObj.comments.filter(c => c.type == "global");
```

and I am wondering if this is a good practice? like if is it bad for the app performance.

Comment: If someone can please suggest a mongoose query that is doing the same!

Answer (score 1):

As JS is single threaded it's better to avoid using filters on db responses. If the comments are too many, it could block the sever. Where as mongodb could handle such operations efficiently

Comment: hm, you're right, I'll just try to learn how to create these complex queries instead, Thank you.